# Where to find existing "track" in release repository?

Tags: ros, bloom-release, release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While trying to push an existing `metapackage` to an existing `release repository` by running `bloom-release` ([tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/bloom/Tutorials/ReleaseCatkinPackage)), I get an error:

```
$ bloom-release --ros-distro groovy qt_gui_core groovy
Given track 'groovy' does not exist in release repository.
Available tracks: ['convert', 'hydro']
```

But browsing [the corresponding git organization on ros-gbp](https://github.com/ros-gbp/qt_gui_core-release), I find `groovy` related branches and tags, while I can't find `convert` thing.

Where are `track`s stored?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59505/where-to-find-existing-%22track%22-in-release-repository?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-03-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tracks are stored on the `bloom` branch in the `tracks.yaml` file:

https://github.com/ros-gbp/qt_gui_core-release/blob/master/tracks.yaml

It was released into groovy with an older version of bloom, you can create a new groovy track before releasing if you want:

```
bloom-release --rosdistro groovy --track groovy qt_gui_core --edit
```

**EDIT** Now the tracks.yaml files are stored on the master branch, hopefully that is more discoverable. Note that they will only be on the master branch once release with a newer version of bloom so some repositories may still have their track files stored in the bloom branch. I also updated the command to reflect the new syntax.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

current groovy bloom, below command line works fine for first release

```
$ bloom-release --new-track --ros-distro groovy --track groovy qt_gui_core
```

---

Originally posted by [ogutti](https://answers.ros.org/users/2408/ogutti/) with karma: 55 on 2013-09-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-04**:
Yup, i updated the answer to use the new format.